# Create a list of lists of tuples where each tuple is the first occurrence of a letter along with its row and column in the list of lists

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, tuples

I need to write a function that creates a list of tuples of the first occurrence of a letter followed by its row and column in a list of lists.

Example Input and Output:

```
#Input:

lot2    = [['.','M','M','H','H'],
           ['A','.','.','.','f'],
           ['B','C','D','.','f']]

#Output: [('M', 0, 1), ('H', 0, 3), ('f', 1, 4), ('B', 2, 0)]
```

As you can see the function should only look for the first occurrence of a letter and not all occurrences. Thanks for any help.

Code:

```
letter = '.abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
def list_cars(lst):
    for y, row in enumerate(lst):
        if letter in row:
            return letter, y, row.index(letter)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, use the string library to get a string of all upper and lower case letters:

```
import string
string.ascii_letters
Out[40]: 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'

collector = []
output_list = []
for i in lot2:
    for j in i:
        if j in string.ascii_letters and j not in collector:
            tmp = (j,lot2.index(i), i.index(j))
            output_list.append(tmp)
            collector.append(j)
```

output_list should give you what you want.

edit: If you want to also capture full-stops use string.printable - although this will give you a string that consists of additional punctuation and white space characters as well.

Comment: when you import string does this also import a period because that is considered part of letters (its confusing sorry) or maybe it has to be done without importing string

Comment: I think I see how it can be done without string I'll let you know if I have trouble

Comment: use string.printable if you want characters other than just upper and lower case English alphabet letters

Comment: I'm running it with test cases and its saying 'TypeError: zip argument #2 must support iteration' not sure what the error is saying

Comment: zip should not have been there; check it now and see if it works.

Comment: Now I'm getting either lot or lot2 is not defined even if i include their definitions in the code not sure why. I have awarded you best answer anyway

Comment: can you post your current code as a comment? The code I edited works just fine for me at the moment.